# TypeError: jQuery(...).live is not a function

Tags: jquery, reveal.js

i am using Reveal modal box jquery plugin but on clicking it show error

```
jQuery('a[data-reveal-id]').live('click', function(e) {
```

Answer (score 2):

```
As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated.
```

Refer [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/#entry-longdesc)

Use,

```
$( 'document' ).on( "click", "a[data-reveal-id]", function() {
});
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are using jQuery >= 1.9, this method was [removed in 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed)... you can include the [migrate plugin](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin) to include the deprecated code as it is inside a third party plugin

Answer (score 0):

**As of jQuery 1.7, the [jQuery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method is deprecated**.

Check the jquery version in your project.

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handlers for newer version.